# Very simple override machine configuration in Yocto

Tags: yocto, yocto-layer

I am trying to override qemuarm machine so that I can make very simple changes like number of CPUs, new kernel configuration and so on. It's not a new hardware but exactly the same with a new name.

I created a layer called meta-ypdd and included in the conf/machine/qemuarm-ypdd.conf presented below.

```
#@TYPE: Machine
#@NAME: QEMU Arm Cortex-A15 machine
#@DESCRIPTION: Machine configuration for running an ARMv7 system on QEMU

require conf/machine/qemuarm.conf
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-yocto-custom"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "qemuarm-ypdd"
```

Two essentials recipes (recipes-core, recipes-kernel) included but I stuck in the error below.

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'quilt-native'
quilt-native was skipped: incompatible with machine qemuarm-ypdd (not in COMPATIBLE_MACHINE)
ERROR: Required build target 'ypdd-image' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['ypdd-image', 'quilt-native']
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you